# during cucumber testing Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

```
manish@ubuntu:~/change/artfacedev2_15july$ bundle exec cucumber features/home_page.feature 
Using the default profile...
Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
Checking for old unconfirmed users
2013-07-23 19:29:38 +0530
Updating CurrencyValue
2013-07-23 19:29:38 +0530
Feature: homepage

  Background: I am on the homepage # features/home_page.feature:3
    Given I am on the homepage     # features/step_definitions/home_page_steps.rb:1
      Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id (RuntimeError)
      ./app/controllers/static_controller.rb:31:in `home'
      ./features/step_definitions/home_page_steps.rb:2:in `/^I am on the homepage$/'
      features/home_page.feature:4:in `Given I am on the homepage'
"Exception"
"undefined method `update_attribute' for nil:NilClass"

..........................
in home_page.feature
Feature: homepage 

  Background: I am on the homepage
  Given I am on the homepage
..........................
in home_page_step.rb
Given /^I am on the homepage$/ do
  visit "/"
end
...........................
path.rb is 
module NavigationHelpers
  def path_to(page_name)
    case page_name
    when /the homepage/
      '/'
    when /users section in backend panel/
      '/backend/users/'
    when /backend login page/
      '/backend/af_login/'
    else
      raise "Can't find mapping from \"#{page_name}\" to a path.\n"
    end
  end
end
World(NavigationHelpers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 31 of static_controller.rb calls `id` on something you expect to be an `ActiveRecord` object, but is in fact `nil`. Work out why.

(The error message is pointing out that `nil`, not being an `ActiveRecord` object, has only the Ruby-internal `id` field, which is always `4` for `nil`).

Comment: in static_controller.rb file i hav contain ID for spacific movie.

    @header_movie  = PAPERCLIP_STORAGE_PATH +  "videos/header_movies   /#{header_movie.id}/#{header_movie.header_movie_file_name}"

Comment: In which case, Rails seems to be complaining that `header_movie` (_not_ `@header_movie`) is `nil`. Perhaps you never set it? I can't help any more unless you can post the method in static_controller.rb that line comes from.

Comment: but once i load welcome page then some MIME type error i got for relate with video file format.
....... like this...... 
HTTP "Content-Type" of "text/html" is not supported. Load of media resource http://localhost:3000/videos/header_movies/1/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm failed. plz guide for this one.

Comment: @manijain - That seems unrelated, although I can't be sure. I don't know of that error. Perhaps your backend is returning HTML when a video has been requested? I suppose it could be related to the `header_movie` variable not being set up. I really am just guessing now.

Comment: yes you are right ... we can't find header_movie variable while load page ... as same case we run test for cucumber we got id for nil ....so i want to know that how can define mime type for video file on mozila. if once i got then sure this test will be run.

Comment: @manijain - sorry, I don't know how you define the mime type for a video file on Mozilla. You would need to ask a new question for that. Be sure to include as much information as possible when you do. If you want any more help here, I really do need to see the method in static_controller.rb that fails.

Comment: i have added one more question for further details .. plz check and give me your reply .. plz thanks